# How to work with files and directories with spaces in them

Tags: unix, terminal

I have ran into this problem many times and searched and searched, but cannot find out how to use, open, remove, etc. files that have spaces in them. For example, I have an image on my desktop named My Text File.txt  . How can I do something with this. i.e. `nano My Text File.txt`  . Whenever I try to do something like this, I get three errors(or however many different blocks of text there are in the file name) each stating the file could not be found because it looks for a file My, then Text, and finally, File.txt. Is there a way to do this without getting errors, or is it possible to create a program to allow it? Any help or advice would be great. Thanks!

Comment: use quotes around file name

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: A backlash just before a space works too.

Comment: From the terminal, if you type `nano My` and then hit `Tab`, your shell will probably complete it to `nano My\ Text\ File.txt`. That's basically what Sung said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appropriate command for opening My Text File.txt would be:

```
nano "My Text File.txt"
```